# Pose bone head and tail position at a frame from python

Tags: python, animation, scripting, pose-mode

I need to get the actual pose bone head and tail position at a particular frame in world space during the animation. Want to avoid calling bpy.context.scene.frame_set as it is quite expensive. Is there a way to get that?

I have tried with `fcurve.evaluate`, but it only returns `location` and `rotation_quaternion` and doesn't take care of the parent-child relations and other things impacting bone location (please refer to [Calculating transformation matrix of a pose bone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302699/calculating-transformation-matrix-of-a-pose-bone)).

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer to: [Calculate a pose bone's transformation matrix from its F-curve without updating](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302699/calculating-transformation-matrix-of-a-pose-bone)

```
matrix = matrix_map[bone.name]
matrixGlobal = bone.id_data.matrix_world @ matrix
headGlobalPos = matrixGlobal.translation

matrix.translation.z += bone.length
matrixGlobal = bone.id_data.matrix_world @ matrix
tailGlobalPos = matrixGlobal.translation
```

(this seems to be working, let me know if there are corrections / refinements)